# Fetch data from XML - differents betwen xml file and fetched data

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I've got a very strange situation. I tried to fetch data from an [xml file](http://www.hurt.moe.pl/api/xml/pl/products/98?key=42274).

Here are a few tags example tags with prices:

```
<stock>9994</stock>
<pricenetto>80.49</pricenetto>
<pricebrutto>99.00</pricebrutto>
```

And I tried to fetch data with this code:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.hurt.moe.pl/api/xml/pl/products/98?key=42274', headers={'User-Agent' :"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"})                    
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        file.write(response.read())
```

My code returns this:

```
<stock>9994</stock>
<pricenetto>20.12</pricenetto>
<pricebrutto>24.75</pricebrutto>
```

Why are the prices different? All of my other data seems correct.

Comment: Have you actually looked at that link? The bottom values are the values in the XML.

Comment: I still have different values, like in my first post. Correct data are in xml (http://www.hurt.moe.pl/api/xml/pl/products/98?key=42274) .  Nick Bailey - do you have the same data in xml and fetched data? Maybe problem is with User Agent - I used few different but that doesn't solved problem.

Comment: I found a problem - default User Agent language is English, and prices are presents in USD. I need to change User Agent language to Polish (added pl-PL): 
`req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; pl-PL; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"})`
But I still have prices in USD.

Comment: Problem solved - adding to header parametr `Accept-Language ` return valid data. Finally I fetch data with this code: `req = urllib2.Request('http://www.hurt.moe.pl/api/xml/pl/products/98?key=42274', headers={'User-Agent' :"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0", 'Accept-Language':" pl, en-US;q=0.7, en;q=0.8"}) `

Thank's for help! :)